# Javascript setInterval while waiting for a GET to complete

Tags: javascript, jquery, setinterval

Hi i am trying to refresh a text in a page that informs about the state of the calculations on the server side, while they are being done. The calculations start with a get request and the refreshing has to happen only while the get has not completed. I am trying to do this by getting the contents of a text file on the server in setInterval and closing that set interval after the GET has been completed. My problem is that when i look at what is happening i only see one request for the text file, at the beginning, and then nothing. I would expect to see a request every 200ms from my code.
I am attaching the js code and thanking u in advance. The function to start by onclick is disps(name);

```
function instant(nn) {
    $.get("./track.txt", function (data) {
        $('[name|="' + nn + '"]').html('');
        $('[name|="' + nn + '"]').html(data);
        /*$('[name|="'+ nn +'"]').first().html('');
        $('[name|="'+ nn +'"]').first().append('<img src="loading.gif">');*/
    });
}

function disps(nn) {
    aa = $('[name|=input_data]').val();
    /* $('[name|="'+ nn +'"]').html('');
    $('[name|="'+ nn +'"]').html('Analysed');
    $('[name|="'+ nn +'"]').first().html('');
    $('[name|="'+ nn +'"]').first().append('<img src="loading.gif">'); */
    var refreshId = setInterval(instant(nn), 200);
    $.get("./loop.php?query=" + aa, function (data) {
        /* $('[name|="'+ nn +'"]').find('img').remove().end(); */
        instant2(nn, refreshId);
        $('[name|="' + nn + '"]').first().append(data);
    });
}

function instant2(nn, refreshIntervalId) {
    clearInterval(refreshIntervalId);
    $('[name|="' + nn + '"]').html('');
    $('[name|="' + nn + '"]').first().html('');
}
```

Comment: Please indent your code correctly.

Comment: Performing HTTP requests while waiting for an HTTP request to complete is sort-of a bad idea.

Comment: @Pointy Yes, but give me an alternative.

Comment: Well, for starters, make the "calculations" take less time so that you don't have to provide status feedback. You might look into web sockets if that's not possible.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
setInterval(instant(nn)
```

This call `instant(nn)` **immediately**, just like any other function call.
It then passes the return value to `setInterval()`, also just like any other function call.

That's not what you're trying to do.

Instead, you want to pass a function that calls `instant()`:

```
function() { instant(nn); }
```

Comment: Yep, that was it,  my bad :) thnx.

Answer (score 0):

classic mistake of activating a function and passing the result value to setInteval, instead of passing the function itself.

Since you want to pass a parameter to the function, and setInterval will not do that for you, you need a closure - which is simple to do -
wrap `instant` in an anonymous function:

```
setInteval(function() { instant(nn); }, 200);
```